# Page Unload Event in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap

I have a cordova app. I that I want do some task like stop the Location service when the user try to leave the page. I have tried the **window.beforeunload** but it didnt not work. Is there a way i can do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform an action (do some task) before the user leaves your app, you can use the `window.onunload` event.